# Polyominoes piece puzzle, image was a storefront

Tags: puzzle-identification, polyomino, jigsaw-puzzle

When I was growing up, my family had a jigsaw puzzle of several store fronts, where you could see different people running, buying, and some kids. All the stores had letters and art. The pieces where based on squares intertwined. Sort of like pentominoes, but could be more or less than 5.

The art was similar to Charles Wysocki. I'm unsure if it is the same.

I have looked for a while and nothing comes close.

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

Mosaic style puzzle named Confection Street

by Charles Wysocki

Comment: Could you provide some images/links to prove that this is the answer?